# How to decrypt with OpenSSL 3.1.0 code encrypted with OpenSSL 0.9.8 using Git?

Tags: git, encryption, openssl

I have some code on an old machine that was encrypted using OpenSSL 0.9.8.

I am trying to pull it on a new machine using OpenSSL 3.1.0.

It does not decrypt when pulling, I don't understand why. I can decrypt using OpenSSL directly, however.

In the git config file; I have something which looks like this:

```
[filter "openssl"]
    smudge = some_path/.gitencrypt/smudge_filter_openssl
    clean = some_path/.gitencrypt/clean_filter_openssl
[diff "openssl"]
    textconv = some_path/.gitencrypt/diff_filter_openssl`
```

And then:

```
    in smudge: openssl enc -d -base64 -aes-256-ecb -k $PASS_FIXED 2> /dev/null || cat
    diff_filter: openssl enc -d -base64 -aes-256-ecb -k $PASS_FIXED -in "$1" 2> /dev/null || cat "$1"
    clean: openssl enc -base64 -aes-256-ecb -S $SALT_FIXED -k $PASS_FIXED
```

I saw that the default message digest had changed between the 2 versions so I tried using the option md md5 but it does not help.

Any idea?

Thank you,
Vincent